# magento2 What is the purpose of email_catalog table

Tags: magento2, database, import-products

I am getting some errors while importing products in admin

Error code is (attached screen-shot)

```
 General system exception happened
    Additional data:
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbname`.`email_catalog`, CONSTRAINT `EMAIL_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `email_catalog` (`product_id`,`processed`,`created_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)
```

As we can see there is one table "email_catalog" creating the problem while inserting the data.

If anybody have know about that table then please let me know what is the purpose of that table.

Where "email_catalog" table is used.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This  tables is create  from `Dotdigitalgroup_Email`module.If you are not using dotdigital for email and marketing then You Need to disable this extension and it will resolved this issue

Comment: thanks @amit , its working fine after disabling module. One thing more suppose in future if we  enable module, what  will impact.Will module work or not since entry will not go that table.Please give your opinion.

Comment: If you will enable this extension in future then same error is happen